# Grouping data of a ListView with integer Keys in Metro-App

Tags: javascript, windows-8

I want to add a semantic zoom to my App. The data contains of a name, a firstname and a unique ID. When grouping the data with the name, everything works. But grouping the data after the id throws an exception.
I'd like it to group like this:

id = 1 --> GROUP 10

id = 9 --> GROUP 10

id = 22--> GROUP 30

Here is what i do:
Namespace

```
 WinJS.Namespace.define("employee",
    {
        groupedNumberItemsList: groupedNumberItemsList,
        itemsListNumber: itemsListNumber
    });
```

Code

```
var itemsListNumber = new WinJS.Binding.List(employeeData);
var groupedNumberItemsList = itemsListNumber.createGrouped(getGroupKeyNumber, getGroupDataNumber, compareGroupsNumber);

function compareGroupsNumber(left, right) {
        return parseInt(left) - parseInt(right);
    }
 function getGroupKeyNumber(dataItem) {
        return "" + 10 * Math.ceil(dataItem.ANNr / 10);
    }
 function getGroupDataNumber(dataItem) {
        return {
            Name: "" + 10 * Math.ceil(dataItem.ANNr / 10)
        };
    }
```

The Exception i am getting:

> SCRIPT5007: Exception was thrown but not handled in user code at line 16182, column 25 in ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0.rc/js/ui.js
>   0x800a138f - Laufzeitfehler in JavaScript: Die Eigenschaft "firstItemIndexHint" eines undefinierten oder Nullverweises kann nicht abgerufen werden.
>   File: ui.js, line: 16182 column: 25

In function addItem of the ui.js the newGroupData is not set and therefore causes the error. But i dont have a clue how to fix it.
Can somebody please help me?

Thanks in advance.

robidd

Comment: Can you provide the data structure of each item in the binding list?